# Binding a DataTable to a Repeater control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

BusinessLogic.EventType :

```
namespace BusinessLogic
{
    public class EventType : IModel
    {
        public int EventTypeID;
        public string Name;
        public string Description;
        public string Photo;
    }
}
```

My Aspx :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 mb">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div style="background-image: url('<%# Eval("Photo") %>'); height: 300px; display: block; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index: 1; left: 0; right: 0">
                        </div>
                        <div style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: 20px; color: #db2828">
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind :

```
public partial class PastOrders : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["vendor"] != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                List<EventType> lstEventType = new List<EventType>();
                EventTypeLogic eventTypeLogic = new EventTypeLogic();
                DataTable dt = eventTypeLogic.SelectAll();

                lstEventType  = (from rw in dt.AsEnumerable()
               select new EventType()
               {
                   Name= Convert.ToString(rw["Name"]),
                   Photo = Convert.ToString(rw["Photo"])

               }).ToList();

                rptr.DataSource = lstEventType;
                rptr.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("VendorLogin.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Now i have used the code provided in one of the answers. Compiles well . But produces a runtime error that  : `System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'BusinessLogic.EventType' does not contain a property with the name 'Photo'.`

my `tblEventType` has following columns  :  `EventTypeID`, `Name`, `Description` and `Photo`.

I do not know what is going wrong!

Comment: So what issue did you get ?

Comment: `lstEventType.Add()` this part .. I do not know how should i iterate through the datatable and assign that values to the repeater.

Comment: @CoderofCode : I hope my question was clear to you ?

Comment: What is the structure of your  `EventType` class ?

Comment: What is the `EventType` ? you are declared as `string` property and in code above you are using it as `Type` ? Does the above code compile at all ?

Comment: Make sure your names are same for `Photo` property as your  exception suggest there is some issue with property name.

Comment: @CoderofCode :  My names are exactly the same. I don't know what it is .

Comment: There is comma after the `photo` property setting.

Comment: @CoderofCode : Did that ..  Still the issue exists..! :/

Comment: @CoderofCode : The issue is solved. Check my New Question based on the same question,  at your will and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have the `EventType` class as below,

```
 public class EventType
 {
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
    ... more properties 
 }
```

and you want to add the database values to the event type hopefully you are creating the list of the objects for your `EventType` class

you can do this as

```
  lstEventType  = (from rw in dt.AsEnumerable()
               select new EventType()
               {
                   Name= Convert.ToString(rw["Name"]),
                   Value= Convert.ToString(rw["Value"]),
                   ... more properties 
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: I am using a 3-tier architecture here. I have C# file in my `BusinessLogic` where i have all the variables declared which are in my database. So now i want to add all the `EventTypes` to my repeater control. Please check my updated code.

Comment: Please try this code and let me know. And you have to change the Property name in `Select` according to your actual properties name from the `EventType` class

Comment: simply i want to add data from my database to the repeater control . Specifically the `Name` and `Image`  values only . I have a utility method `SelectAll` which returns  a `datatable` .

Comment: please check my updated code. I have provided with all the necessary code. And the code you provided gives me a runtime error. Please check my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Something Like this using `Named Arguments`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
lstEventType.Add(new EventType(){
EventType=dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString()

});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataTable dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  lstEventType.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Yourcolumn"].ToString());
 }
```

Comment: Bt i am going to add two properties of the table : `Name` and `Image` .. Still it will be the same code ?