# How to convert a repeater control into grid view control in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am having a repeater control in my Asp.Net application, I just want to change this repeater into grid view control because i want to apply paging. i didn't want to add custom paging in repeater instead i want to use default grid view paging .

can any body suggest me what changes are required??

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest Use Jquery Paging instead.

convert repeater to Gridvue https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26344088/convert-from-repeater-to-gridview.html

Binding a DataTable to a Repeater control in ASP.NET [Binding a DataTable to a Repeater control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556770/binding-a-datatable-to-a-repeater-control-in-asp-net)